# Preventing postback of bootstrap dropdown

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the bootstrap dropdown component, which for me currently looks like this:

```
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" id="btnSaukList" data-toggle="dropdown" runat="server" style="width: 100%">
                Select a Saukville contact
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul id="ulSaukContact" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" runat="server" style="width: 100%">
                <!--NOTE: Intentionally left blank; li's are generated by code behind to populate users from Sharepoint.-->
            </ul>
            <input id="inpSaukValue" type="hidden" />
        </div>
```

([default code sample here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns) - as you can see, mine isn't that different structurally)

My problem is that every time I click a dropdown item, a postback is fired (browser jumps to the top of the page). I'm pretty sure this is because the default code Bootstrap uses is `<button>` which always includes a postback.

According to other SO articles regarding this issue, it's recommended to use an `<input>` or `<asp:Button>` instead. Well I can't do either...

- `<asp:Button>` does not support text between the opening and closing tags.
- `<input>` does not support the `data-toggle` attribute, which it seems the dropdown needs.

I've also tried adding `onclick="return false;"` to my `<button>` to no avail.

I'm new to bootstrap and to an extent, ASP.net.

**UPDATE**:
It wasn't a postback, it was a link to "#", I was confused, sorry!

Comment: @Adriano I added `runat="server"` so I can use the value in code behind... I'll update my question

Comment: I added that but I got the same thing.

Comment: I think it may have have something to do with the href. If you look at the original code snippet they provide, each list item has `a href="#"`. Now I'm trying to find a way to bypass that, because if I remove the `<a>` link completely, I can't click items at all, I'd have to rewrite the css probably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I was confused about this one, and labelled the problem as a postback - it wasn't. In Bootstrap's default code snippet, every dropdown item includes a link to "#". Clicking a link to that(`<a href="#">`) will send the browser to the top of the page. I thought this was a page refresh but it wasn't actually refreshed.

A quick fix is to replace `href="#"` with `href="Javascript:;"`. If anyone has a better solution, do share...